# C# How to set control height in relative height

Tags: c#

My form contains a tab control. On one tab, I have three groupboxes. Each groupbox must have the height of one third of the height of the tab.

Right now I have this code on the layout event of the tab control:

```
        // Determine the position of the group panels (gp)
        this.SuspendLayout();
        int oneThird = (tabPanel.Height - 5) / 3;

        if (_currentQuestion != null && _currentQuestion.QuestionTypes == QuestionTypes.Infofield)
        {
            gpExplanation.Visible = false;
            gpFillInHelp.Visible = false;
            gpFillInQuestion.Height = oneThird * 3;
        }
        else
        {
            gpExplanation.Visible = true;
            gpFillInHelp.Visible = true;

            gpFillInQuestion.Height = oneThird;
            gpExplanation.Height = oneThird;
            gpFillInHelp.Height = oneThird;
        }

        // Determine position of the appointment and achievement group panels
        int height = tabPanel.Height - 30;
        int half = height / 2;

        pnlAppointment.Height = half;

        this.ResumeLayout();
```

I also have this code in the constructor of my form:

```
// Set styles which prevent screen flickering
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

What is in your eyes the best way to set the height of the groupboxes? When the form resizes, the groupboxes height must be one third of the panels height.

I also want as less as possible flickering on the screen.

Comment: It seems as though they alway remain the same relative size, so why don't you simply set the Anchor and/or Dock properties in the designer?  You could also use a FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for this. In the panel you can specify the `RowStyle` 
such that it sized as a percentage of the parent control:

```
tableLayoutPanelGroupBoxes.ColumnCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanelGroupBoxes.RowCount = 3;
tableLayoutPanelGroupBoxes.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
tableLayoutPanelGroupBoxes.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
tableLayoutPanelGroupBoxes.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
```

Just set the `DockStyle` on your group boxes to `DockStyle.Fill` and add them to the table layout panel. You can use the designer to do this.

Comment: Thnx, this works, but when resizing the window, it still flickers a lot. How can I prevent the screen from flickering?

Comment: Try with a BeginUpdate() and an EndUpdate()

Comment: Where should I use that? I use a TableLayoutPanel now and let the control handles the height now. Where should I place the Begin- and EndUpdate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use Achor property of the group boxes.

Comment: How do I set the anchor setting for each groupbox? I mean which groupbox does have which anchor setting

Comment: I think the group boxes should set with top right anchor setting, if they placed below one after another. After all it depends on your screen